# $.post not posting the data to the specified page

Tags: php, jquery, html

I used `$.post` to pass the value from current page to another page in order to delete some data. But the value is not getting posted. I tried with `.get` too, still not working. Please suggest a way to fix the issue.

```
<i title="Delete" class="icon-remove-sign icon-2x" onClick=" myFunction('<?php echo $val['id']?>','delete_pahse')"></i>
<script>
    function myFunction(rowId,delet) {
        if (confirm("Are You Sure to Delete ") == true) 
        {
            $.get("?action=studentDetail&student_id=<?php echo $_GET['student_id'];?>&rowId="+rowId+"delet="+delet),(function(data){
                document.getElementById('progress').style.display = "none";
                    if(data){
                            alert('The Selected Record Is Successfully Deleted');
                    }else{
                            alert('The Selected Record Is Not Successfully Deleted');
                    }   ;
            });

        }

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Never use get to delete data(just post and make sure isn't accessible from from spiders/crawlers); also see that get have a limit( those were suggestions cause I don't understand to good your question)

Comment: your code is vulnerable to xss

Answer (score 0):

In send.php

```
  <?php
  $mydata="This is my string being passed to another php";
  header("Location: http://xyzphp.in/Receive.php?msg=$mydata");
  ?>
```

In Receive.php

```
<?php
$receive = $_GET['msg'];
echo "Data Received";    
echo $receive;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing an '&' before 'delet=' in your $.get url. This would cause it to mess up the rowId - instead of rowId=5 it would see rowId=5delet=.

Answer (score 0):

@user3300358, Can you please try with below JS Code :

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"YOUR URL",
    data: { student_id: student_id, rowId: rowId, delet: delet},
    success : function(data) {
        if(data){
            alert('The Selected Record Is Successfully Deleted');
        } else {
            alert('The Selected Record Is Not Successfully Deleted');
        }
    },
    error : function() {
        alert('Something went wrong. Please try again');
    }
 });
```

Let me know if still you have any issues.

Comment: please explain why this is work and code in question doesnt work ?

Comment: @obi NullPoiиteя kenobi I have mentioned to him that his code is not working & he wants to do the same with POST method.So I have given above code with POST Method.